# How to config Bespin Embedded like that?

Tags: bespin

How to setting a save, undo, redo button on the top bar of bespin like this image:

http://bengalbraith.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/editor.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those kinds of buttons are tied very much to a server implementation. Adding them to Bespin Embedded requires basically creating a toolbar plugin with the buttons you need. The start of a generic toolbar plugin is here:

http://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/2010/07/03/tutorial-adding-to-bespins-gui/

One note: in the current Bespin Embedded release, it's not as easy to run a command programmatically as I would like (which is what the toolbar would need to do). Look for that to become better in a future Skywriter release.